Filter metrics by tag value using .net OpenTelemetry
I'm using .net OpenTelemetry for metrics instrumentation in a .net8.0 console application.
    services.AddOpenTelemetry()
        .WithMetrics(builder =>
        {
            builder
                .AddMeter("System.Net.Http")
                .AddView(instrumentName: "http.client.open_connections", MetricStreamConfiguration.Drop)
                .AddView(instrumentName: "http.client.connection.duration", MetricStreamConfiguration.Drop)
                .AddView(instrumentName: "http.client.request.time_in_queue", MetricStreamConfiguration.Drop)
                .AddView(instrumentName: "http.client.active_requests", MetricStreamConfiguration.Drop)
                .AddView(instrumentName: "http.client.request.duration", new MetricStreamConfiguration
                    {
                        TagKeys = new string[] { "http.response.status_code", "server.port" },
                    })
                .AddOtlpExporter((exporterOptions, metricReaderOptions) =>
                {
                    exporterOptions.Endpoint = new Uri("http://localhost:4317");
                });
        });

I noticed that measurements for OTLP exporter requests are also collected (gRPC requests over port 4317).
As http.client.request.duration metric has a tag port, can I filter out measurements by tag value?

The title asks one thing, the question another. Why are you trying to filter meters in the first place? The values aren't generated by AddMeter, this only specifies that OpenTelemetry should read the already available metrics under Systen.Net.Http and send them whenever a monitoring application asks for them on 4317

updated the question. I was hoping to drop measurements with port == 4317

There is no ability to filter metrics based on tags today in OpenTelemetry .NET.
